# Run Sublime Text 2 from the command line

Tags: sublimetext2, ubuntu-14.04

I run this:

```
$ sublime .
```

and it opens the current dirctory, which is exactly what I want. **However, I cannot use my terminal window because now it displays the following:**

```
(sublime:10715): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1678 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime:10715): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 3156 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime:10715): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 3162 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

How can I run the sublime command and have it run the background. There's no daemonize option:

```
$ sublime --help
Sublime Text 2 Build 2221

Usage: sublime_text [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: sublime_text [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit
```

I can't use `subl` either:

```
$ subl .
No command 'subl' found, did you mean:
 Command 'subs' from package 'libsubtitles-perl' (universe)
 Command 'publ' from package 'atfs' (universe)
subl: command not found
```

I'm running ubuntu-14.04

Comment: `sublime` should (at least in my experience) daemonize automatically. What happens if you just hit `Enter` after the GLib messages appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
sublime . &
```

This will run it in the background.

If you want to use subl instead of sublime, change the name of your sublime.exe to subl.exe.